# Terminal shows more files on desktop than there are actually

Tags: unity, command-line, files, duplicate-files

I noticed this thing today and found it to be awkward. My desktop has the following files :[image: Desktop]

But upon running `ls` in the terminal i got the following output:

```
 a.out    htc_pass.sh              openmp.cpp~  test.cpp
he.cpp   imp gcc update commands  t.cpp~       test.cpp~
he.cpp~  misirlou (copy).ogg      test2.cpp~   trial.c~
hello    openmp.c                 test.c~      Untitled Document 1~
```

And it is quite clear from the terminal output that the number of files according to it is much higher than what can actually be seen. Why is this happening?

Comment: The files with the ~ at the end... Those look like temporary files that the desktop is hiding... this isn't a bug, by the way, it's probably a function of the desktop.

Comment: @ThomasW., okay, but for files which have been deleted a long time back, why is the desktop storing temp files? can it be stopped?

Comment: Read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the backup files created by you text editor when you edit a file .It is equivalent to `*.bak` in windows .Although they are pretty handy at times you can turn them off if you desire.

These are specific to the text editor you use but still I can give simple way to turn them off for the two most used text editors

if you use `vim` add this line to your `vimrc`
`set nobackup`

If you use `gedit` 
In gedit preferences disable `Create a backup copy of file before saving`

If you use any other specific editor search for the specific way to turn off the backup file creation for the same

Answer (score 2):

They are a backup files, gedit creates them for every edited file. Nautilus hides files .starting_with_dot or ending_with_tilda.txt~ , unless you tell him to show hidden files (ctrl-h or in the menu).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you're seeing in `ls` are temporary files and are being automatically hidden by the Desktop.  The files with `~` at the end are sometimes created by text editors and other programs which edit things.  The system does not automatically remove them, and some programs don't autoremove them.  Some programs will remove the files, but others won't.  The files are still there because nothing removed them.

You can remove those pretty easily, however this command here to do so has not been tested thoroughly by myself so be careful with using this:

```
cd ~/Desktop
rm *.cpp\~ *.c\~ Untitled*
```

I am uncertain whether those are being automatically hidden in the desktop, however that is what I believe is happening based on what you've said.